# Who will get the point in this case?

Tags: rules, officiating, badminton

We need your help about this case in our badminton match (shuttlecock side (A) and racket side (B)):

*The shuttlecock and racket both touch the net at the same time (the shuttle isn't falling down, it's just touchs the net).*

Can anyone tell me who will get the point in this case (shuttlecock side or racket side)? And it would be great if you can tell us that's following what are the rules/laws?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who hit the shuttle in which situation. According to the [Laws of badminton](http://system.bwf.website/documents/folder_1_81/Statutes/CHAPTER-4---RULES-OF-THE-GAME/SECTION%204.1-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton%20-%2005012018.pdf):

> §14.2.3.2 It shall be a let if, after the service is returned, the shuttle after passing over the net is caught in the net;

So if the racket side hit the shuttle during the rally, it's a let, i.e. you replay the rally.

In all other cases, it's a fault of the side which hit the shuttle:

> §13.2.2 It shall be a fault if, in service, the shuttle after passing over the net, is caught in the net.
>
> §13.3.2 It shall be a fault if, in play, the shuttle fails to pass over the net;

While the shuttle is in flight, the latter rule does not apply. Per §15.1, only if the shuttle is caught in the net and starts to drop down, the fault is called.

So much for the shuttle side. When the racket touches the net, it's a fault as well:

> §13.4.1 It shall be a fault if, in play, a player touches the net (..) with racket (..).

---

Assuming the shuttle side hit the shuttle last, you have to evaluate what happened first - per §15.3, the first fault ends the rally.

- If the racket touched the net before the shuttle hit the net, it's a fault of the racket side and the point goes to the shuttle side.
- If the shuttle hit the net and started falling downwards (even a little bit of tumbling) before the racket hit the net, then it's a fault of the shuttle side and the point goes to the racket side.
- If the shuttle got caught in the net just as the racket hit the net and you can't decide which happened first, it's a let, per §14.2.7.

Comment: The shuttlecock and racket both touch the net in the same time.

Comment: We're thinking about the rules: 15.1 and 15.2 (13.4.1 also). We want to make sure who will get the point in this case.

Comment: I have amended the answer. If shuttle and racket hit the net at the same time and you can't decide what happens first, it's a let. In a match without an umpire, as a general rule of thumb it's also a let whenever there is disagreement. On the chair, I'd call whichever fault I saw first.

Comment: This is an image only so we suppose the shuttecock and the racket both touch the net at the same time + the shutte isn't falling down (see the image, it only touchs the net). The situation: we only see the image and how to know who will get the point that's all.

Comment: Just by the image, there's no way to decide. For instance, if the racket side served and the shuttle got stuck in the net, the point would definitely go to the shuttle side. You can speculate (maybe the net deformation indicates that the shuttle was hit from the shuttle side), but there's no way to be sure. You can just list all possibilities, which is what I tried in the answer.

Comment: We think the shuttle is still in the match because it doesnt hit the court (15.2) or its not falling downwards also (15.1) so the racket touch the net while the shuttle in the play so it's falut of the racket side (13.4.1). Is this right ?

Comment: Or we think it's fault of the racket side because if the racket didnt touch the net then the shuttle won't flight like that (normally, it can fly/flip on the net...)

Comment: That is certainly a valid interpretation, even a likely one. In practice, umpiring does not happen on still pictures, but on games with situations. That's also the reason why all of the umpire tests and discussions I ever had were in the form of descriptions or videos.

Comment: One could reasonably assume that the shuttle got smashed into the net from the left, thereby moved the net, and only then the net and racket touched.

Comment: Yes, we thought that case. If the racket didn't touch the net (and shuttlecock also - see image) then the shuttle can flip the net (the shuttle in the play and we don't know what happen with it, so don't touch the net when its in the play = its fault of the racket) :-)